# Group policy - deploying printers

Tags: windows, group-policy, windows-xp

I am trying to deploy printers using group-policy, we have a mixed domain of XP and windows 7 pc's I've used the printer management console to deploy the printers and its been smooth enough for the windows 7 PCs. The XP PCs are a different story, from research I need to D/L  PushPrinterConnections.exe and copy it over to the listed folder.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc722179%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

My problem is I cannot find PushPrinterConnections.exe anywhere, its not on ms web-site. Is there a better/quicker way of deploying printers to 32 bit XP machines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's part of the [Server 2003 admin pack](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=9bfb44f5-232a-4fb5-bc14-45bfd81b7ac1&displaylang=en). I'm not sure how hard you googled for this, because there are a large number of correct results when searching for `where is pushprinterconnection.exe`

That said, [GPP](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732092.aspx) is the modern way to deploy printers and will work on all currently supported operating systems, including XP as long as it is fully patched. GPP is much more flexible than the "Deploy Printers" option from the print management console.

Comment: Thanks but that 32bit client that contains pmcmgmt.exe not pushprinter.exe, thats my issue.

Comment: If you extract the contents on pmcmgmt.exe, you'll get what you're looking for. Really, this is all over google.